# How to use a 1 line javascript builder pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Any javascript builder pattern I have seen constructs the desired object in 2 steps:

```
var foo = new Foo()
var desiredfoo = foo.func1("something").func2("something");
```

Is there any way to use it like java ie without breaking lines ?

```
var desiredfoo = new Foo().func1("something").func2("something");
```

Comment: That second example should work, you've just refactored the code to remove the `foo` reference, but I suspect that's not what you were asking.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pn7pL/ . What is your *real* question?

Comment: "there is nothing like constructor in javascript" all functions can be called as constructors with the `new` keyword.

Comment: @Hamish thanks for pointer.  New to javascript and missed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `func1` and `func2` both return `this` then your two examples are equivalent.

The builder pattern might be overkill for JavaScript though since you can use object literals for defaults. e.g. `new Foo({value1: 9, value2: "hello"})` and have your constructor process those.